# How to change php-fpm default port?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, fpm

I'm using `php-fpm` which runs for default on the port `9000`. The problem's that I have other docker container based on `php-fpm`, so I need to change the default port to another one, in order to not confuse `nginx`.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-alpine
RUN sed -i 's/9000/9001/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

WORKDIR /var/www/html

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9001
```

I tried to use the `sed` command to replace the port `9000` with `9001`.

Inside my `docker-compose` file I have this configuration:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  php-fpm:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/php-fpm/config/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
      - ./src/public:/app/public
      - ./src/writable:/app/writable

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${HOST}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${HOST}
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${EMAIL}
```

as you can see I have exposed the port `9001` also in the `docker-compose` file.

The file `default.conf` available within `conf.d` folder contains this:

```
upstream php-upstream {
    server php-fpm:9001;
}
```

the problem's that for some reason, when I load my site I get the error 500. So this means that the stream doesn't send any signal. If I change to port `9000` everything works, but the stream is wrong 'cause it's the content of another application.

How can I correctly change the default port?

Comment: any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Iman unfortunately the best solution in that case is use different names for each `php-fpm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is not the sed command itself, it's related to the wrong file you mentioned for it.

```
/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
```

this is the file you are trying to change the port in it but inside your docker-compose file you are mapping something else

```
./docker/php-fpm/config/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Comment: I changed in `www.conf` file this line: `listen = 127.0.0.1:9001` in particular, I've specified the port `9001` but actually I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your nginx docker connects via the internal docker net work, your docker host port mapping `9001:9000` is not taken into account.

If your php-fpm is really listening on port 9001, then that is the port you must use in your nginx config.

Also `EXPOSE` is primarily declarative and does not expose anything by itself (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) the corresponding service must still be configured correctly to use that port.

Answer (score 0):

for this line in Dockerfile is not working(?):
`RUN sed -i 's/9000/9001/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf`

so I decided to make this change after the container is up with:

`docker exec -i your_container bash -c 'sed -i 's/9000/9001/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf'`

and then restert the container to make changes happened

hope help you

Comment: I tried this solution too.. but the main issue is that php-fpm stream for default to the port 9000. So, even if you change the port, you will create conflicts over the other services which uses php-fpm with the same name, eg: nginx. I discovered this behavior using a proxy, I don't know if without proxy this works

Comment: after that you can set different names for your containers in docker-compose.yml file and map them with their names in nginx config file. i don't have any issue any more